# Another way of using COUNT(DISTINCT column) OVER(...)

Tags: sql, mariadb

My desired output is something like:

﻿[image: "16924595" "35" "16924595" "40" "16924595" "45" "16924610" "35" "16924610" "40" "16924610" "45" "16924644" "35" "16924644" "40" "16924644" "45" "16924648" "35" "16924648" "40" "16924648" "45" "16924666" "35" "16924666" "40" "16924666" "45" "16924697" "45" "16924705" "35" "16924705" "40" "16924705" "45" "16924716" "35" "16924716" "40" "16924716" "45" "16924773" "35" "16924773" "40" "16924773" "45" "16924797" "35" "16924816" "35"]

My attempt is as follows:

```
SELECT id, g_minute, COUNT(DISTINCT id) OVER(ORDER BY f_datetime DESC) AS counter FROM tbl_X
```

When I try this I get:

> This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'COUNT(DISTINCT) aggregate
> as window function' */

Is there another 'simple' way of doing this? I want a cumulative counter of unique id's. Is there another `window` function that can do the same thing?

Comment: It looks like you need to use `dense_rank`

Answer (score 0):

Try a nested window function instead:

```
SELECT id
    ,g_minute 
    ,sum(seqno = 1) OVER (
        ORDER BY f_datetime DESC
        ) AS counter
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id ORDER BY f_datetime DESC
            ) AS seqno
    FROM tbl_X t
    ) r
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I get the count of values when I'm testing

```
SELECT
     ID,
     G_MINUTE,
     COUNT(ID)
FROM tbl_X
GROUP BY ID, G_MINUTE
```

This will give you the distinct count of the ID and g_minute